# A lamp with height (h) and some other things, so find (h)

Tags: geometry, derivatives, circles

"If a lamp with height ($h)$ was at  point $(-2,h)$, and the light ray that comes from it touches circle $(x^2 +y^2 = 1)$ at a point in the first quarter, and then stops when it hits the x axis at point $(1.25,0)$, so find the height ($h$)".

What I have understood is:

1.A triangle with sides ($h$, the x axis from -2 to 1.25 and the light ray) forms.

2.the light ray touches the circle in one point so i think we need the derivative somehow

3.if the light ray is going from
x = -2 to x = 1.25 and it is going from $y = h$ (which is obviously positive) to $ y = 0$, then it is going to go through the y axis at some point which i we dont know.

What do i want? just (h)

Comment: I think it's easier to imagine the light beam going the other way: It starts at $(1.25,0)$, touches the circle somewhere in the first quadrant, and then stops when it hits the vertical line $x=-2$.

Comment: The slope of a line tangent to the circle is $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$. You have two  points on the line so you know its slope so that should be enough to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Points are labelled as shown.

[image]

1. Using the right-angled triangle SAD to find $\angle SAD$ which is the same as $\angle BCD$ (because ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral).
2. Find $\angle XSD$ which is $90^0 + \angle BCD$
3. Use point-slope form to get the equation of SDC.
4. Solve x = -2 and the equation in step 3 to get h.

Almost there.

Comment: I can see that im very bad at geometry, anyway i appreciate your help!

Comment: @AmrWaleed If you need help, just let me know and I can add in some details. And I have just added some steps.

Answer (score 0):

The line segment $A(-2, h)$ to $(1.25, 0)$ is tangent to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  Therefore the distance between the origin (which is the center of the circle) and the line segment is $1$.

Now, we just need to find the equation of the line segment, and this is given by

$ y = \dfrac{ h }{-2 - 1.25 } (x - 1.25) $

Cross multiplying yields

$ -3.5 y = h (x - 1.25) $

The distance from the origin $(0,0)$ to this line is given by

$ d = \dfrac{ | -3.5(0) - h( 0 - 1.25) | }{\sqrt{3.5^2 + h^2 } } = \dfrac{1.25 h}{\sqrt{3.5^2 + h^2 } } $

Since $d = 1$, then

$ 1.25^2 h^2 = 3.5^2 + h^2  $

From which

$ h^2 = \dfrac{3.5^2} { \bigg(\dfrac{9}{16}\bigg) }$

Taking the square root

$ h = \dfrac{ \bigg(\dfrac{7}{2} \bigg)}{ \bigg(\dfrac{3}{4}\bigg) } = \dfrac{14}{3} $

Comment: I really appreciate your help! but can you tell me the formula you used for the distance?

Comment: Certainly.  The distance of a point $(x_1,y_1) $ from the line $ ax+by+c=0$ is given by $d=\dfrac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is the first time that i see this formula.